# Line number swiped in UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, react-native

I am working on a react-native app that needs to detect which line number in a [`TextInput`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) (`UITextfield`) has been swiped by a user.

A popular app that uses this type of interaction is Paper which allows a user to swipe a given line in a text document to style it.

[image]

Even though my main use case is react-native, curious to know what other developers familiar with RN or iOS think are the building blocks for such an interaction.

My current thoughts are:

- Wrap my `TextInput` with a `PanResponder` element
- Detect whatever I consider is a valid user gesture
- Determine the `x,y` coordinate of the valid gesture
- Somehow determine the sentence that was swiped on given the above coordinates??

Comment: That looks a UITableView. All that functionality is built in. If you want even more control, have a look at UICollectionView

Comment: `UITableView` looks like it is used to display hierarchical lists of information; which works for my use case. I am not sure if this control though allows a user to "Select All" and highlight all of the text in the view; or whether it would only select the current row.

Comment: A common way of dealing with selection in table views is to have the selected state managed by an underlying model. Use that model to show / hide some icon on your cell that represents a selected state. Use the table views didSelect callback to update your model. Call the cell reload methods to display the new state once the model is updated. For select all, just update all model objects to be selected, then reloadData on the table view. Table views do support single / multi selection, but I've often found it simpler to manage it myself. Try both and see what works best for you.